# How to cast IDictionary<string, object> to IDictionary<string, MyType>

Tags: c#, casting, idictionary, memorycache

I'm using the default `MemoryCache`, which works fine for my purposes.  However the `GetValues()` method returns `IDictionary<string, object>`

Is there a quick way to cast this to `IDictionary<string, MyType>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx):

```
ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => (MyType)k.Value)
```

Comment: DOH! So simple...works nicely with a generic method to return exactly what I want every time.

Comment: @BlueChippy , Remember to mark the answer . This will help others also.

Answer (score 0):

Do your own `GetValues` method that call to the original one. For each result, do the cast to the second returned value (the object one) and generate your own casted `IDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

This would mean that you can only store objects of type `MyType` inside this cache. But if this is the case you could have a wrapper method:

```
public static IDictionary<string, MyType> GetValues(IEnumerable<string> keys)
{
    return MemoryCache.Default.GetValues(keys).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value as MyType);
}
```